# A cute two variable inequality involving logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

A cute inequality of my invention:

Let $z>0$ and $z>x,y>0$. Then

$x\ln (\frac{z}{z-y})>y\ln (\frac{z}{z-x})$

implies $x<y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  let $a = x/z, b = y/z\,$, then $a,b\in (0,1)\,$ and the inequality can be written as:

$$
\frac{1}{y} \ln\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{y}{z}}\right) \gt \frac{1}{x} \ln\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{x}{z}}\right) \;\;\;\iff\;\;\; \frac{\ln(1-b)}{b} \lt \frac{\ln(1-a)}{a}
$$

The problem then reduces to showing that $\,\displaystyle \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Yes in fact it's trivial I just thought it's cute

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou I would call it a good practice problem, maybe not the most difficult, but not exactly trivial, either. It does take a few steps to "homogenize" the variables, then separate them and reduce the problem to a matter of monotonicity. Recognizing the patterns and connecting the steps together is precisely what a good practice problem is meant for.